# Pseudocode: \Function vs. \Procedure?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, pseudocode, algorithmic

The title says it all.

What is the difference between a `Function` and a `Procedure`?

When should I use which?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to `algpseudocode`, these two are structurally the same, apart from their name:

```
\algdef{SE}[PROCEDURE]{Procedure}{EndProcedure}%
   [2]{\algorithmicprocedure\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicprocedure}%
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
   [2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%
```

From a programming perspective, the difference is embedded in the language and have the following commonly-used structure (in laymen's terms):

- **Procedure**: A collection of instructions
- **Function**: A collection of instructions that also returns something

A minimal example indicating their typical usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{name}{params}
  \State body
\EndProcedure
\Function{name}{params}
  \State body
  \State \Return something
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: should we specify the output of Function somewhere or it is just specified through `return`?

Comment: Is it the standard, if we mention both input and output parameters in {params}

Comment: @RenjthVRavi: That depends. This is pseudo-code, so as long as it's clear in the presentation.

Comment: A function, depending on definition, also does not modify state (*has side-effects*).

Answer (score 8):

This is not at all a TeX-related question, but a function returns a value while a procedure does not (`void` in C++). A procedure only performs some actions, it is invoked because of its side effects.